# find and replace in notepad++ or vscode

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code, notepad++

Sorry all guys, use the code to make it more clear and convenient. I have

```
pre-fec-ber-min { description "pm for terminal-device, includes minimum only"; }
post-fec-ber-min { description "pm for terminal-device, includes minimum only"; }      
all { description "all of pm parameter type"; }
```

and I want to change it to

```
pre-fec-ber-min
post-fec-ber-min
all
```

The purpose is to remove all the brackets, so I can just copy it to define enum. Please tell me what I should write in find and replace in notepad++ or vscode?

Comment: Better to show your code before and after as actual code not images.  And you should show what you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An exact match might use the following find and replace:

```
Find:    ^(\w+)\s+\{.*?\}
Replace: $1
```

This would capture the first word term at the start of the line, removing the bracketed expression which follows it.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode:

- Select 1 open brace `{`
- Select All Open braces <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Select till End of line: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- delete via <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- stop multi cursor: <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: @Toto These are the default shortcuts, look up the key for `Select All`

Comment: @Toto -  from the docs: Ctrl+Shift+L Select all occurrences of current selection editor.action.selectHighlights **DEFAULT**

Comment: @Toto: VSC v1.42 (there seam be some problems with v1.43)

Comment: OK, my comment refers to Notepad++. Forget it ;)